# How to use data bound value to form unique identifier for item control?

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I know that we can bind the data to each control within ItemTemplate as follow:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("LabelText") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

However, I found no way to concatenate a string prefix with the data value to form a unique string identifier. The following code shows my idea, but it doesn't work.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
         ID='TextBox_<%# Eval("LabelID") %>'
         ValidationGroup = 'VVG_<%# Eval("LabelGroup") %>'
         Text='<%# Eval("LabelText") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us how it doesn't work. What behavior is your code creating?

Comment: e.g. the result of the ValidationGroup would be: "VVG_<%# Eval(\"LabelGroup\") %>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

<strike>ID = '<%# "Text_" + Eval("LabelID") %>'</strike>

```
ValidationGroup = '<%# "VVG_" + Eval("LabelGroup") %>'
```

EDIT:

ID cannot be assigned in this fashion for server side controls. You can assign ID for simple form controls such as  `<input type="text"... />`. Also take a look at [Control.ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) (ASP.NET 4).

Comment: I don't thinks this will work, when I tried to run an example with it I got an error saying **Parser Error Message: The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example: `<asp:Button runat="server" id="Button1" />`**

Comment: @R0MANARMY did you try it in the ItemTemplate of a repeater?

Comment: Inside the ItemTemplate part of a repeater, I can post my code if you'd like.

Comment: @Bala R: I guess more specifically, I don't think (according to the error) it'll work for the ID field but should be fine for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"         
    ID='<%# String.Format("TextBox_{0}",Eval("LabelID")) %>'         
    ValidationGroup = '<%# String.Format("WG_{0}",Eval("LabelGroup")) %>'         
    Text='<%# Eval("LabelText") %>' />
```